jest error: cannot find module 'import-local'
I want to test my typescript functions in vscode using jest, so I installed jest using the instructions from the quick start guide on jest.io (https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started). After running the jest command in my terminal, I get the following error message:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'import-local'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/jest/bin/jest.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/jest/bin/jest.js:9:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/share/nodejs/jest/bin/jest.js' ]
}

Node.js v20.11.1


My package.json file looks like this:
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "import-local": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}

